# How to show that $ P(|f-A|\ge C)\le K_1\exp(-\delta_1C^2) $ from median concentration?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $\mu$ is the Borel probability measure. $f: X\to R$. If there exists $K_4, \delta_4$ s.t. for all $C>0$, $$P(|f-M_f|\ge C)\le K_4\exp(-\delta_4 C^2)$$ where $M_f$ is the median of $f$. Then
there exists $K_1, \delta_1$ and $A\in R$ s.t. for all $C>0$,
$$
P(|f-A|\ge C)\le K_1\exp(-\delta_1C^2)
$$
where $K_1\le K_4\le 4K_1$ and $\delta_1\ge \delta_4\ge \frac{\delta_1}{32}$.

Can we can choose $A=M_f$....?

---

I try to show that
$$
P(|f-A|\ge C)\le P(|f-M_f|\ge C/2)+P(|M_f-A|\ge C/2)\le K_4\exp(-\delta_4 C^2)+P(|M_f-A|\ge C/2).
$$
But how to bound the second term?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @JoseAvilez I just want to make sure that if we can choose $A=M_f$?